# Поэлементное сравнение массивов с поиском ближайшего варианта

Tags: массивы, menu, php, сравнение

В друпале есть такая функция "меню". Одна из ее задач - прочитать путь, который запрашивает пользователь и попытаться найти ближайшее соответствие.

Например, есть путь: node/12345/edit

Под него могут подойти следующие:

> `node/12345/edit - точное соответствие. Ценность 7 (111)
> node/12345/% - последнее имя заменено на placeholder. ценность 6(110)
> node/%/edit - 101
> node/%/% 100`

Дальше - больше:

> `node/12345 - 3 (11) два первых слова совпадают, третьего вообще нет: теряем порядок
> node/% 2 (10)
> node 1 (1)`

Грубо говоря, тут реализовано что-то типа бинарного сравнения. Есть/нет.

Вопрос: возможно ли подобное сравнение реализовать простыми методами, типа "$arr1 & $arr2"? Очень не хочется копировать оттуда длиннющий кусок кода.

P.S. друпал в метках не указан, так как он тут почти не при чем.

Comment: Думаю, стоит смотреть в сторону регулярных выражений и поэлементно сравнивать массивы.

Comment: не, вместо регулярок тут вполне сгодится explode. А насчет поэлементного сравнения ~рожа-бритого-Николаса-Кейджа~ об этом и вопрос!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Смущает то, что node/%/edit лучше, чем node/12345.
Сравнение видится таким, в качестве отправной точки:

```
$weight = 0;
for ($i=min(count($a),count($b))-1;$i>=0;$i--){
  $weight |= ($a[i] && $b[i] == $a[i]);
  $weight <<= 1;
}
$weight <<= (max(count($a),count($b))-min(count($a),count($b)));
```

где $a - проверяемый url, $b - введенный.

ЗЫ надеюсь, я правильно понял о чем речь =)

Comment: @knes, ну я подозревал, что разные элементы могут иметь разный вес изначально, но вот если мы редактируем статью, то лучше зайти в саму статью, чем узнать что нам надо редактировать неизвестно что.

Comment: .

    $a = array('node','1234','edit');
    $ba = array(array('node','1234','edit'),
         array('node','1234','%'),
                array('node','%','edit'),
                array('node','%','%'),
                array('node','1234'),
                array('node','%'),
                array('node'));

    foreach($ba as $b){
      $weight = 0;
      $right_placeholders = 0;
      for ($i=min(count($a),count($b))-1;$i>=0;$i--){
 $weight <<= 1;
 if($weight==0 && $b[$i]=='%'){
   $right_placeholders++;
 }
      $weight |= ($a[$i] && $b[$i] == $a[$i]);
    }
    $weight<<=$right_placeholders

Comment: Вот так заработало как в примере выше. Но в общем, главное, вы подали замечательную идею. +v

Comment: то лучше зайти в саму статью, чем узнать что нам надо редактировать неизвестно что// Тут не совсем так. Если пользователь введет node/%/edit, его пошлют куда подальше. Потому что % - это плейсхолдер. Он специально как раз для того, чтобы скрипт мог сгруппировать одинаковые микродействия на разные однородные статьи. Почему тогда не node/edit/%? Потому что с точки зрения человеческого языка действие над объектом есть принадлежность объекта.

Comment: Ну это все зависит от конструктора url (про друпал не знаю как там положено). Можно завести веса для каждой части url и получать вес не в порядке следования, а в заданном. т.е. веса (1,3,2) для /node/%/edit дадут 110, а для (1,2,3) дали бы 101. Выглядело бы это не сдвигом разряда, а & с 1<<(вес i-й части url).

Comment: Я с бинарными операциями плохо обращаюсь. Я их понимаю, но не могу представить в голове. 
Что же касается более сложной системы веса, это, возможно, тоже будет добавлено. Пока что хотелось внедрить примерно как то, с чем я долгое время работал, чтобы не приходилось переучивать.