# Маршрутизация по ЧПУ для блоков

Tags: php, mysql

Есть сайт, на котором несколько страниц, глобально выполняющих разные функции.
("статьи", "каталог", "новости", ну, как обычно.)
Каждая страница имеет один/несколько блоков, которые зависят от адреса(например, на странице статьи текст зависит от адреса, ес-но) и несколько не зависящих(блок последних новостей, мини-каталог, корзина...).
Вопросы:

- На кого возложить ответственность за преобразование ЧПУ в айдишники?
- что делать, если надо конкретный блок вставить куда-то еще, где, в норме, неподходящий адрес?
- где хранить связку ЧПУ-id, если учесть, что название страницы новости и статьи могут быть одинаковым, различие только в /articles/часть_ЧПУ или /news/часть_ЧПУ

сейчас, к сожалению, все тупо: каждый текстовый кусок имеет в базе специальное поле, содержащее его название в ЧПУ. Это неудобно, так как придется изменять во всех блоках, если будет изменено в одном.

была мысль составить словарь, но запутался что в этом словаре будет ключом.
module+ЧПУ? но тогда, опять же, придется писать отдельный костыль для того чтобы была возможность показать статью в произвольном месте.

Последний вариант - создать полный список страниц со всеми блоками, которые в них есть.
Айдишник - полный адрес страницы.
Плюс: карта сайта будет собрана в секунду. 
Минус: нафиг не нужен [маршрутизатор](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/127729/php-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%8D%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D1%81%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D1%81-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC-%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B6%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%88%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B0), который сейчас занимает табличку из всего 15 строк и работает идеально, теряется гибкость системы.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Мне кажется что, конкретно в этом случае, универсальность - это зло. Есть какой-то определенный алгоритм по которому, допустим, на странице со статьей или со списком  статей должен выводиться блок с последними новостями. Статья это основная сущность, а блоки - это обвеска из дополнительного контента способствующая удобному переходу в другие части сайта. И вывод этого самого блока никак не должен быть связан с URL. Из URL получаем только то что это статья и какая именно, а наличие блока с новостями на странице статьи - это запрограммированное поведение.